# Why does the parameter "disabledwidth" of a tkinter canvas rectangle not work?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I want the outline of a rectangle in a canvas to get a bigger width, when the rectangle is in state "disabled". Therefore I use the parameter "disabledwidth=4". But when the rectangle is in state "disabled", the outline has still a width of 1 instead of 4.

This is my code, which shows the problem: When I move the mouse over the rectangle, the state of the rectangle changes to "active", everything works as expected, especially the outlinewidth changes to 4. But when I change the state to "disabled" by clicking on the button the outline stays at width 1. What am I doing wrong?

```
import tkinter as tk
def disabled():
    canvas.itemconfig(rect, state="disabled")
def normal():
    canvas.itemconfig(rect, state="normal")
root    = tk.Tk()
canvas  = tk.Canvas(root, height=250, width=250)
button1 = tk.Button(root, text="change rectangle to state disabled", command=disabled)
button2 = tk.Button(root, text="change rectangle to state normal"  , command=normal  )
rect = canvas.create_rectangle(40, 40, 180, 180,
                fill           = "red",
                activefill     = "green2",
                activeoutline  = "green3",
                activewidth    = 4,
                disabledfill   = "grey",
                disabledoutline= "grey2",
                disabledwidth  = 4
                )
canvas.grid()
button1.grid()
button2.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's might be not supported by the operating system and an "underdocumented" feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a very old but simple bug in Tcl/Tk which causes `-disabledwidth` to not be parsed properly for rectangle and oval canvas items, causing it to be silently ignored (at least in some cases). I reported it to Tcl/Tk along with the fix: https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/info/f4d9d74df628

So hopefully this will be fixed in Tcl/Tk 8.6.14 (which hopefully will then be used in future Python distributions).

Answer (score 1):

Specify the width in `canvas.itemconfig`

```py
import tkinter as tk

def disabled():
    canvas.itemconfig(rect, state="disabled", width=4)

def normal():
    canvas.itemconfig(rect, state="normal", width=1)

root    = tk.Tk()
canvas  = tk.Canvas(root, height=250, width=250)
button1 = tk.Button(root, text="change rectangle to state disabled", command=disabled)
button2 = tk.Button(root, text="change rectangle to state normal"  , command=normal  )
rect = canvas.create_rectangle(40, 40, 180, 180,
                fill           = "red",
                activefill     = "green2",
                activeoutline  = "green3",
                activewidth    = 4,
                disabledfill   = "grey",
                disabledoutline= "grey2",
                width          = 1
                )
canvas.grid()
button1.grid()
button2.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Edit: This appears to be a genuine bug. I have filed a [report](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/103216).

Comment: This answer gives only a workaround, but not an explanation why the parameter "disabledwidth" does not work.

Comment: @MatthiasSchweikart You know, I ended up looking around and couldn't find anything about anyone experiencing that issue. I ended up filing it as a bug, because it appears to be so: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/103216


The documentation here says that it should work:
https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/create_rectangle.html